# SVG icon is not showing up in a Qt, portable application under Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, svg

For some reason, I want to publish my application as a portable one. That is, avoiding the pre-installed shared libraries and use my own ones, shipped together with the app.

Long story short. Following the advises on [this helpful page](http://goblincoding.com/2013/11/07/deploying-qt-5-applications-on-ubuntu-12-04/), I found that the window icon, which is an svg, not showing up in the foreign computer. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a shared library it needs cannot be found.

In Windows, you have to put `Qt5Svg.dll` in the same folder of the exe. And in Linux, besides the `libQt5Svg.so.5`, **iconengines/libqsvgicon.so is also needed**.